# How can I resize li elements at certain breakpoints using media queries?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries, html-lists

I've made a block of social media icons at the bottom of my page.

I'd like to make them half-sized for screens smaller than 375px but my media query isn't working.

Here's some of my CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 275px) {
.custom-social-icon
    padding:5px 7px;
}

.fa-facebook {
padding:10px 14px;
transition: .5s;
background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="footer-social-icons">
<ul class="social-icons">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook custom-social-icon"></i></a></li>
```

When I resize the screen to smaller than the breakpoint, the icons stay the same size. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some curly brackets inside your media query '{}'

```
@media (max-width: 275px) {
 .custom-social-icon{
   padding:5px 7px;
   }
  .fa-facebook {
    padding:10px 14px;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This code, It may help you. Here you change css as given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media (max-width: 375px) {
      .fa-facebook{
         padding:5px 7px !important;
            }
      }
    .fa-facebook {
      padding:10px 14px;
      transition: .5s;
      background-color: lightsteelblue;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="footer-social-icons">
      <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook custom-social-icon"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiran  This worked! I actually have 6 icons. I've done this for each one but I assume there's a way to apply it to all the icons at once.  Any idea how? I can't work it out. Thanks!

Comment: Add same class name to each of icon .And add common property inside that class name.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Kiran

Comment: Most Welcome@sim

Answer (score 1):

Its just a simple mistake in your code.
Replace your media query with this and it will works perfectly.

```
@media (max-width: 275px) {
 .custom-social-icon {
  padding:5px 7px;
 }

 .fa-facebook {
  padding:10px 14px;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
 }
}
```